# How can I test my international IP detection script?

Tags: testing, proxy, geolocation, ip

I want to test my international IP detection script on my web site.  How do I setup a proxy so that my web site thinks that I am coming from a foreign iP?  Specifically in this case I'm looking to test from Canada, Germany, UK and France.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a web proxy from any of these countries and point it at your site/script.

[Here](http://www.freewebproxylist.com/) is a list of many free web proxies - there is a breakdown by country. Canada, Germany, UK and France are all on the list.

Comment: is there a way so that I can setup my browser to SPOOF as if it's coming from an IP in another country so that I can browse and watch what's coming across the wire (XHR) at the same time.

Comment: @Chris - That's not how TCP/IP works... You will need separate computers for the server and browser and monitor both. It can't be (easily) done on one computer.